# Regex to avoid apostrophe character at end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below regex expression. I want to avoid  `'` this character at end of string. I am able to avoid in staring and in between of the String but not able at the end of the String.

```
^[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d- ]*[a-zA-Z'-\'\d]$
```

e.g.

`'test` -> Not Valid (Above expression is working for this to avoid)
`test's` -> Not Valid (Above expression is working for this to avoid).
`test'` -> Not Valid (Above expression is **not working** for this to avoid)

Comment: So, you want to avoid apostrophe at all?

Comment: Change `[a-zA-Z'-\'\d]$` to `[a-zA-Z\d-]$`

Comment: Poorly worded question: Regex to avoid apostrophe character at end of the string

Answer (score 0):

What I've understood is that you want something like "If there is an apostrophe at any place of a string then it is invalid". If I  understand correctly then you can try this regex-

```js
const regex = /^((?!\').)*$/;
const inputs = [
    "test'",
    "'test",
    "te'st",
    "text"
];

inputs.forEach(input => {
    if (regex.test(input)) {
     console.log(`${input} is valid`);
    } else {
     console.log(`${input} is invalid`);
    }
})
```

**P.S:** If I understand incorrectly then comment for correcting me.